# Unexpected http status error in Amazon SES API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use Amazon SES API to send mail using PHP. I am following [this](https://github.com/zshannon/Amazon-Simple-Email-Service-PHP) github example.

My php code is like following:

```
<?php
    if (!class_exists('SES')) require_once 'SES.php';

    // AWS access info
    if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'my_key');
    if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'my_secret_key');


    // Check for CURL
    if (!extension_loaded('curl') && !@dl(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'so' ? 'curl.so' : 'php_curl.dll')) exit("\nERROR: CURL extension not loaded\n\n");

    // Instantiate the class
    $ses = new SES(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

    //Verify your Email Address
    echo "SES::verifyAddress(): ".print_r($ses->verifyAddress('myemail@mydomain.com'), 1)."\n";
?>
```

When I run this file in browser I gets following error:

```
Warning: SES::verifyAddress(): [0] Unexpected HTTP status in /home/www/mail/SES.php on line 82
SES::verifyAddress():
```

My domain is working and my website is running on it. Also, I am using same access key and secret key in my outlook to send mails with my verified email id. Do anybody know what could be the problem?

Note:- I have a self-signed ssl certificate on my server created using openssl.

Comment: Did you verify your sending address on the form on the right side of the SES page: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/ ?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, did you resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue.